# Android Service Callback method to Activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-service-binding

I have a Activity and a Service.  I am using bindService to get the Binder object which gives my activity access to the service.  So I am able to execute commands on the service easily.  What I need is a way to have the service communicate back to the activity.  Is the best way to handle this to make calls directly from my activity to the service via the service instance returned from the binder.  Then use a local broadcast receiver to send messages back from the service to the activity?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this.
1.You can pass a handler object to the service, and have it implement the [handler callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.Callback.html)
2. You could send a [broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
3. You could pass a listener object.

variant number 1 is usually best if you know exactly the activity you pass the reference to. 
If you want several activities to handle it, better send a broadcast